# Drools DMN Required dependency not found on node. message-type: "REQ_NOT_FOUND"

Tags: drools

I am quite new to Drools and I'm stuck with creating a first DMN.
The problem is that for some reason input is not recognized as a dependency.

This is my settings for DMN:

[image: My settings for DMN]

So when I try to access the REST endpoint for this container/DMN - I always get the following result:

```
{
"dmn-message-severity" : "ERROR",
"message" : "Required dependency 'InputData' not found on node 'Release?'",
"message-type" : "REQ_NOT_FOUND",
"source-id" : "_282A92B2-1837-4000-B2C4-1769E91F16B2"
}
```

Which settings am I missing?

I used the Docker installation from https://drools.org/

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found out why this happens. The error description was a bit misleading.

It actually cannot find 'InputData' in **my request** to Drools but not in the model structure.
My request was not correct. For the model above - the request has to be as follows:

```
{
    "model-namespace": "https://kiegroup.org/dmn/_E7AF3B9E-C5F3-47C0-855E-EDB912F647EB",
    "model-name": "release-rule",
    "dmn-context": {
        "InputData": {
            "MessageAmountOriginal": 5000
        }
    }
}
```

I.e. it starts from dmn-context and should repeat the DMN data structure.

Hopefully, it will help someone else out there